# Proving a subspace for a polynomial set

Tags: linear-algebra

Lets define $X$ a set as
$X=\{p∈P_3|p(x)=xf(x)+(1−x)g(x)\}$,
for some $f,g\in P_2 \subset P_3$
Determine if it is a subspace for $P_3$

So I have trouble proving the zero vector within the set. Can anyone advise me how to start?

Comment: Sure: take $f(x)=g(x)=0$.

Comment: Actually I'd say $X=P_3$.

Comment: I don't think you have written this correctly: the phrase " for some $f,g\in P_2$" has to be **inside** the braces of the definition.